# Synchronise SPI: options? Dedicated reset line? Series of reset bytes not allowed in data? Long break?

Tags: spi

When using SPI, is there a common way of ensuring that when sending 8-bit words, that the sender and receiver know what is the start and end of a byte?

I'm guessing the best way is to assume that some period of no clock pulses from the master should be interpreted as a sort of reset, so the slave should assume any incomplete bytes/words should be abandoned, and the shift register reset? Is there some standard length accepted as a reset, either in multiples of some clock frequency, or some absolute time period?

Comment: Most (all)? dedicated SPI controllers only run the clock *during data transfer*. Why can that not synchronise you?

Comment: Have you examined how your devices treat the select signal?

Comment: The chip-select/slave-select pin is pretty much always used for this purpose.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you having an issue where the slave SPI device has its clock out-of-sync with the master SPI device? (I've had this problem in the past). You can't easily fix that problem once it happens, but can more easily prevent it from ever happening.

Comment: The last time I used SPI, there was no such thing as an incomplete byte/word. If you shift N bits in then they will be in the shift registers, regardless of "how many bits" you shifted before.

Comment: And "how many bits" is quoted, because SPI shift registers are not capable of containing partial bytes/words. They always contain the same number of bits even if you don't know what some of those bits are.

Comment: @immibis - but if there were four bits in the slave's shift register, and the master shifts in another byte, four bits complete the first byte, and the next four start a new byte. The slave gets a completion interrupt, so things look normal, but the data is wrong. SPI slaves that reset their bit-counter with chip-select don't have this problem, but many don't do that (there is no "official" SPI spec). How the slave got screwed-up in the first place is the real issue. From first-hand experience, it can happen.

Comment: @Mark An SPI device should not process the word in its shift register until you tell it to. Otherwise daisy-chaining would be impossible.

Comment: @immibis, and how would you tell it? Normally the byte is automatically transferred from the shift register to the receive buffer as soon a the eight clock occurs (even though the slave may think the wrong clock is the eight clock). It sounds like the SPI that you're dealing with is different than what I'm use to (as I said, there is no standard).

Comment: @Mark With the SS (or CS) line. The devices I've used required the master to pull SS high, shift data, then pull SS low for a certain time, during which the contents of the shift register would be interpreted as a command and replaced with the result (which could be shifted out by pulling SS high again).

Comment: @immibis, yes, and that works when it works. But what happens if SS is de-asseted prematurely? Or if a device doesn't clear its bit counter on SS? Or the master starts transferring when the slave is not yet ready? I'm simply saying that there are many ways that an SPI slave can get out of sync. The challenge is in determining how it happened.

Comment: @Mark "If SS is de-asserted prematurely" then what happens for any other hold time violation? You get unpredictable behaviour. "If a device doesn't clear its bit counter on SS" doesn't make sense because the devices do not have bit counters. "Or if the master starts transferring when the slave is not yet ready?" - the slave is always ready to transfer data when SS is high unless you have a hold time violation.

Comment: @immibis, 1) yes, hold time violations are a possibility. 2) MANY devices (maybe most?) use bit counters to know then to transfer from shift-register to holding buffer. Any device that does not require SS to toggle on every byte would need one. 3) "The slave is always ready"? Now you're being naive.

Comment: @Mark That is how the SPI devices I've used worked. And yes, SS was required to toggle on every byte - I repeat, daisy-chaining would not work otherwise.

Comment: @immibis, I would respectfully disagree about daisy chaining. On one of my servocontrollers, I have a two 12-bit DACs (DAC8143FS), two digi-pots (AD5260) and a shift register (74HC595) in one long 48-bit daisy-chain that I drive from a MC9S08GB60 MCU. I assert SS, shift 48 bits (6 SPI transfers) and then de-assert SS to latch all 5 devices simultaneously. There are probably 101 ways to use SPI.

Comment: @Mark "I assert SS, shift 48 bits, and then de-assert SS" - yes, and that only works because those devices do *not* use "bit counters". Otherwise, you'd shift 8 bits, it would get replaced with a response from the first device (assuming all 8-bit devices), and that response would get shifted to the second device, which would interpret it as a command and replace it with its response, which would then get shifted to the third device, ...

Comment: @immibis, Yes, That's true. That particular application will never have the problem of bits getting out of sync. I've mainly seen the sync issue when SPI is used for inter-processor communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPI master and slave sync based on the `slave select` signal. They should stay synced by always counting the bits in lock step after the initial `slave select`.

[image]

The SPI protocol depends on master and slave being able to remain in sync. If they get out of sync, then there is a deal-breaker problem someplace that needs to be fixed. Good places to look are noise and level problems on the signal lines, or software implementation bugs, or buffer overruns.

Comment: They SHOULD stay synced. And anything that causes them to go out of sync is a serious bug. But I think the OP is saying that it HAS gotten out-of-sync, and wants to know how to recover. If so, then what he really needs to know is how it went out in the first place, and how to fix it.

Comment: @Mark agreed. edited to reflect. thx.